# Why my image positioning in svg has an offset of 22?

Tags: image, svg, position

I try to position an image inside a svg graphics to the left border, but with x=0 the image has a offset of 22. When x=-22 it fits, but why?

This is my svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?> 
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 

<svg width="400px" height="200px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<image x="0" y="50" width="200px" height="100px"  href="data:image/png;base64,__base64data__" />
</svg>
```

And here is the result:
[image]

When I reduce x to -22 it looks fine, but it should be 0, shouldn't it?

```
<image x="-22" y="50" ...
```

[image]

How can I fix it? Where does the margin comes from?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without knowing more about the referenced image, this is speculative: if the aspect ratio of the PNG does not match the ratio of width to height of the image element, it will be uniformly scaled to just fit the image dimensions and placed in the middle. Either use a fitting aspect ratio, or set [`preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute).

Comment: Thanks a lot @ccprog My Image is letterboxed. Doh! What a fail of mine. See: https://github.com/petershaw/svg-test/blob/master/cat.png You saved my Sunday.